# Spring Data Cassandra: How to define a Repository for a table with composite primary key?

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

This is my table;

```
@Table
public class Opinion {

    private String text;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String topic;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String owner;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    ...
}
```

How can I declare a Repository for this table with a composite primary key? This is what I have now but it does not work, probably because of the ID part, since my id is not just a string but a composite one.

```
@Repository
public interface OpinionRepository extends CassandraRepository<Opinion, String> {
 ....

}
```

By the way I would be glad to hear your experiences whether Cassandra plays nicely with Spring Data or not.. Actually I have been using Spring Data for a while, and I have to say that this time with Cassandra was everything different. Even for some very simple stuff which one can deal with easily on other databases, I have hard time figuring it out. And some of the stuff was not supported at all.. So I am actually very disappointed about Cassandra-Spring Boot interplay.

Comment: I dont think that spring data goes well with cassandra. I would suggest to use the cassandra-driver only.

Comment: thanks :/. i switched to mongodb, and everything looks a lot better on coding level